# pixel shader and vertex shader problem in visual studio 2008

Tags: shaders, .net

I have just installed XNA for VB2008 professional, now i try to run my first game development and i get this error,

any way around this, am using windows xp sp3

[image]

my system configuration

```
Host Name:                 USER-PC
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows XP Professional
OS Version:                5.1.2600 Service Pack 3 Build 2600
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Uniprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          user
Registered Organization:   user-pc
Product ID:                55274-640-1011873-23081
Original Install Date:     1/26/2011, 7:00:52 PM
System Up Time:            0 Days, 10 Hours, 31 Minutes, 22 Seconds
System Manufacturer:       Hewlett-Packard
System Model:              HP d330 uT(DC579AV)
System type:               X86-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: x86 Family 15 Model 2 Stepping 9 GenuineIntel ~
2593 Mhz
BIOS Version:              COMPAQ - 20031003
Windows Directory:         C:\WINDOWS
System Directory:          C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume1
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
Time Zone:                 N/A
Total Physical Memory:     1,527 MB
Available Physical Memory: 689 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  2,048 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 2,008 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    40 MB
Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
Domain:                    WORKGROUP
Logon Server:              \\USER-PC
Hotfix(s):                 10 Hotfix(s) Installed.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing a quick google search on your PC model number led me to this page: http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/11647_na/11647_na.html

The important bit is this:

> Intel 865G chipset with Integrated Intel Extreme Graphics 2

Which, according to a few sources I found, seems to not support shaders.

You need a new graphics card.

Comment: can you suggest the graphics cards that support pixel shading?

Comment: Men! I said that first, not fair :)

Comment: Pretty much any card you can buy would work.